# opencart module development error ( what the best resources to start learn opencart extension development )

Tags: opencart, opencart-module, opencart-3

i start to create my custom module I have this error
"Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp64\www\perfor-opencart\system\engine\loader.php on line 83"

open cart version 3.*

my controller is :

```
class ControllerExtensionModuleFetchddatasmarterp extends Controller {

private $error = array(); 

public function index()
{ 
$this->language->load('module/fetchdatasmarterp'); 

//$this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title')); 

$this->load->model('setting/setting'); 

$this->load->model('module/fetchdatasmarterp');

}
}
```

my view is empty also my model is empty language have some vars

the extension that I need to create is so easy just get products data from external JSON uri and then insert these products to my opencart DB pllllllz help me

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem just by change the name of view and model